# Issues with storage upgrading RHEL 7 to RHEL8

Tags: linux, linux-server, rhel-7

I am attempting to upgrade RHEL7 to RHEL8 using LEAPP. I have corrected all errors the preupgrade scan flagged. The last error I am receiving is that there is not enough space

```
Disk Requirements: At least 223MB more space needed on the / filesystem.
```

I have plenty of space though: 42GB of unused space on the `/` partition, 835MB downloaded for the upgrade. Any help with troubelshooting this issue is greatly appreciated.

```
Error Summary
-------------
Disk Requirements:
   At least 223MB more space needed on the / filesystem.



============================================================    
                       END OF ERRORS                        
============================================================


Debug output written to /var/log/leapp/leapp-upgrade.log

============================================================
                           REPORT                           
============================================================

A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.json
A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt

============================================================
                       END OF REPORT                        
============================================================

Answerfile has been generated at /var/log/leapp/answerfile
[root@rh7 ~]# df -hT
Filesystem            Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs              devtmpfs  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 tmpfs     1.9G  9.0M  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                 tmpfs     1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root xfs        50G  6.2G   44G  13% /
/dev/mapper/rhel-home xfs       484G  172M  484G   1% /home
tmpfs                 tmpfs     379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/995
/dev/sda1             xfs       2.0G  165M  1.9G   9% /boot
tmpfs                 tmpfs     379M     0  379M   0% /run/user/0
[root@rh7 ~]#
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is try setting this variable:

```
export LEAPP_OVL_SIZE=3000
```

The leapp installer creates a container overlay image in /var/lib/leapp.  The default size is 2048MB.  The LEAP_OVL_SIZE environment variable can be set to increase the size in MB of this image.

The error message is sort of misleading but in general, since it says you need at least 223MB, we want to change this value to at least 2048 + 223 + (some additional space).  3000 is a good place to start in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. We need to prevent `leapp upgrade` from trying to install them. Do this for all packages in the list that cannot be installed. So I removed the current version of all packages that were going to be updated and manually installed them via `rpm` binaries.

For example, let's say package `iwl7260-firmware` cannot be installed due to lack of space. First we remove the package and then install it via `rpm`:

```
yum remove  iwl7260-firmware
rpm -i https://repo.almalinux.org/almalinux/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/iwl7260-firmware-25.30.13.0-111.el8_7.1.noarch.rpm
```

After that, run `leapp update` again.